# Cannot get admob to show up over my surfaceView

Tags: android, admob, adview

I cannot get admob to show up on top of (in a Z-axis kind of way) my surfaceView (what I call renderView).  Here is the code I'm using to setup my layouts and views.
The adView is working in that if I exclude the surfaceView from the layout it shows up where I would expect it too.  Otherwise all I see is my surfaceView occupying the entire screen. Thanks!

```
private void createAdNew() {

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adViewLayoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adViewLayoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    adView.setLayoutParams(adViewLayoutParam);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    renderView.setLayoutParams(surfaceViewLayoutParam);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    RelativeLayout adViewLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    adViewLayout.setLayoutParams(adViewLayoutParam);

    RelativeLayout parentLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    parentLayout.addView(renderView);
    parentLayout.addView(adView);   
    parentLayout.setLayoutParams(parentLayoutParam);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("6EA60118611111EB4F201E157VC99EBF")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    Log.d("Ads", "Before");
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);       
    Log.d("Ads", "After");
    setContentView(parentLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting a background color on the AdView should make it work:

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/avwVXvBt_sM) if you still encounter problems

Comment: It's a workaround, more of a hack we use..and yes, it works regardless of the color you set. There's currently no explanation for why it works :(. Hopefully we'll find out soon

Answer (score 0):

This is one method I use:

Create layout that will host the adView with the positioning you like called ad.xml in this case

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/hostad"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

after having already set your ContentView

```
addContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ad, null), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

then add the adView to the layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad);
layout.addView(adView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have given the RenderView layout params of Match_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT. Ie you have told it to conusme all the space of its parent leaving none for the AdView.

If you intend to keep on using RelativeLayout then you need to configure the AdView first and tell the RenderView to be above/below the AdView.

Or you can use a LinearLayout and give the RenderView `layout_gravity="1"` which will tell it to consume all space not already used by the AdView.

NB I strongly recommend that you define your layout in XML instead of programatically. This would have been much simpler and quicker to resolve in that form.